# When removing required modifier from field in ASP.NET Core MVC validation still enforces it as required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-11.0

I have a DTO that gets passed to my controller, where a field is marked as `required`, for example:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost("person")]
    public async Task RegisterPerson(Person person)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

This works fine, and ASP.NET Core MVC validates that `Name` is passed in the DTO. However, when I remove the `required` modifier, I still get the validation error. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution doesn't help.

Is this a bug? And how can I fix this?

Comment: You probably need to declare it as `string?` type, indicating that you expect it can be null.

Answer (score 1):

To disable validation on a property you can use
[Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
public string? Name { get; set; }
```

or apply the [`[ValidateNever]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) attribute:

```
[ValidateNever]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `required` modifier is meant to help at compile-time: `new Person()` will cause a compiler error unless it's followed by an initializer like `new Person {Name = ...}`.

You can use a nullable type to indicate that you think of that property as "optional":

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This will help ASP.NET's bindings to not worry if the property is omitted (or has a `null` value provided). It will also provide you with compiler warnings if you try to use `Name`'s value without checking whether it's null first.

Answer (score -1):

You should also modify your csproj or namespace to remove the     `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` or `#nullable enable` to allow the string be null by default.

Like below:

[image]

Then inside the codes, you will find there is no need to add ? to set the string be null and then model validation will be true.

[image]